# How does one prevent sweaty palms when playing the drums?

Tags: technique, drums

I have sweaty palms, and it makes my drumsticks slip from my hand from time to time whenever I stroke too fast. Would chalk help or are there any solutions for drummers who have the same issues?

Comment: Tape around the stick? Gloves?

Comment: Have you tried to change the material of the sticks?

Comment: @drummin wouldn't tape around the stick make it harder to grip/feel your drum sticks

Comment: @Flugueubluck how would that help?

Comment: @Nick I mean sometimes you will be more sweaty when you use wooden sticks than with carbon fiber sticks. I mean it will slip less easily perhaps, you should give a try

Comment: there are lots of brands of wax which will help your hands, the most interesting of which is named Sex Wax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend trying something called "tennis overgrip". You can buy it at any store that sells tennis stuff. It is quite thin and very absorbent. You just wrap it around your sticks and you are good to go. It is quite thin and does not change the feel of your sticks nor does it make it harder to grip.

Answer (score 1):

I've been playing for over 20 years.
I've tried playing with various gloves and tapes/wraps.

Nothing works as well (or feels as good) as playing with nothing between you and the drumstick.

I've owned a leather stick bag for nearly 20 years now, and I think it makes the difference.
If I take a set of sticks right out of the paper sheath, sure they'll be clean and slick.
But by putting them in my leather bag, it imparts a certain humidity to the stick.

You can go with the stick dressing or gloves, if you want.
If that doesn't work, try a leather stick bag.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use a sports resin [rosin] pad, but more recently I discovered lawn bowls wax.
The method I use is to rub a small amount onto my hands then quickly onto every set of sticks I'm likely to use that night, it's pretty efficient & can be re-applied as often as necessary. Usually one application lasts an entire night.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it a few years with different kind of wraps/tapes (hockey grip tape etc), it gave me enough grip but I never liked the feeling & hated WHEN it got a bit messy because of dissolving adhesives. :)

I ended up with covering the grip of my 5B sticks with a few 1 inch long rings of thin heat-shrink tubing (sometimes a bit sanded).

Rings instead of covering the whole grip because it creates thin edges with more grip & you still have at least some spots with nothing between the stick and your skin. :)

There are a lot of products (non-slip heat-shrink tubing for knife handles, fishing rods, medical & food grade hs-tubing etc.) but I always used the "normal" types of tubing you find in every electronics store.